# How to reduce noise 'salt and pepper' from images in matlab?

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

I have a list of images containing noise with the method 'salt and pepper'. I want to *reduce* the effect of noise in the image, so that it is not be completely removed. Is there a way to do this?

Here is an example image:
[image: example]
I tryed to use this code :

```
im = imread('D:\Documents\MATLAB\1_Para2.tif'); %// 

 image = imnoise(im,'salt & pepper',0.01); %L-image

 M = medfilt2(image);
 imshow(M)
```

After applying this code, the noise is removed from this image but My goal is to reduce the noise. How can I do it, please?

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "reduce the noise"
Do you want to reduce its amplitude? Or do you want to have less spots? do you want to specify how much it is reduced? What is the goal of that? What do you want to achieve? Help us understand your problem as a whole.

Comment: @ Piglet My goal is to reduce the noise by having less spots.

Comment: apply median to random only to a random subset of pixels then.

Answer (score 0):

To remove/reduce salt and pepper noise like in your image you can apply a median filter.

http://de.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/medfilt2.html

Morphological operations provide another way to success.

Comment: I tryed to use this function, but it removed the total noise, I want simply to just reduce the noise.

Comment: @yosra well this is a pretty awkward question because nobody wants to have any noise :)  Sorry if I misread your question. Normaly everyone is happy if the noise is not just reduced but removed.

Comment: @ Piglet I nkow, but the goal is to test the influence of the performanceof system when images contain noise

Comment: @yosra then I suggest you use noise free images where you add artificial noise of your choosing instead of trying to reduce existing noise.